# Unable to write or read a file in external storage - Android

Tags: android, file, file-io

I am trying to write a simple program that writes a file to external storage and reads from it. The following is a description of the problem:
1. File name = "hello_files.txt" containing text "hello world" stored in `/sdcard`.
2. Once the data to the file is written, the file can be seen with `adb`.
3. However, once the application is loaded on to the phone and looked at with a third party file explorer app, there seems to have been no text written to the file hello_files.txt.It seems that there is a problem with the writing part of my program, but I cannot figure out what. I have given below both portions of the code, for writing as well as reading.

The code for reading from a file:

```
   public void readFromFile() {

            //Step 1. Check if the storage is available. 
            boolean mStorageAvailable;
            boolean mStorageReadWrite;

            String state = Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED;
            Log.v(this.toString(), "State of media = " + state);

            if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                Log.v(this.toString(), "Media is mounted.");
                mStorageAvailable = true;
                mStorageReadWrite = true;

                File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                String fileName = dir + "/" + file;
                Log.v(this.toString(), "Reading from file = " + fileName);

                File f = new File(dir, file);

                FileReader fr = null;
                try {
                    fr = new FileReader(f);
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "Wrapping a buffered reader around file reader.");
                    BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(fr, 8192);
                    //Log.v(this.toString(), bufRead.toString());
                    String line;
                    try {
                        line = bufRead.readLine();
                        Log.v(this.toString(), "Line read = " + line);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), line, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.v(this.toString(), "IOException found in reading line from file.");
                    }   
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "File not found for reading.");
                }
            }
}
```

The code for writing to a file is:

```
 public void writeToFile() {

        //Step 2. Check if external storage is mounted. 
        boolean mStorageExists;
        boolean mStorageReadWrite;

        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        Log.v(this.toString(), "External media mounted state = " + state);

        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            //media is mounted.
            //Mounted storage is read/write. 
            //Write to the file.

            mStorageExists = true;
            mStorageReadWrite = true;

            Log.v(this.toString(), "Going to write to a file.");

            //get directory.
            File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            Log.v(this.toString(), "Root directory = " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
            String fileName = dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + file;

            Log.v(this.toString(), "File to write to is present at " + fileName);

            File f = new File(dir, file);

            FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                Log.v(this.toString(), "File not found.");
            }
            try {
                fos = openFileOutput(file, MODE_WORLD_READABLE | MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
                Log.v(this.toString(), "Bytes of the string = " + str.getBytes().toString());
                fos.write(str.getBytes());
                //Log.v(this.toString(), "Local path = ");
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.v(this.toString(), "File not found!!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v(this.toString(), "IO Exception.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            //media is mounted but read only.
            mStorageExists = true;
            mStorageReadWrite = false;
            Log.v(this.toString(), "The media is read-only mounted.");
        } else if( (Environment.MEDIA_NOFS.equals(state)) || (Environment.MEDIA_REMOVED.equals(state)) || (Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED.equals(state))) {
            mStorageExists = false;
            mStorageReadWrite = false;
            Log.v(this.toString(), "There is some problem with the media.");
        }
    }
```

The log (from the `Log` verbose tags):

```
10-23 10:26:19.444: V/com.sriram.fileops.MainActivity$2@44e95cc0(466): Read from file button clicked.
10-23 10:26:19.444: V/com.sriram.fileops.MainActivity@44e90428(466): State of media = mounted
10-23 10:26:19.444: V/com.sriram.fileops.MainActivity@44e90428(466): Media is mounted.
10-23 10:26:19.444: V/com.sriram.fileops.MainActivity@44e90428(466): Reading from file = /sdcard/hello_files.txt
10-23 10:26:19.453: V/com.sriram.fileops.MainActivity@44e90428(466): Wrapping a buffered reader around file reader.
10-23 10:26:19.453: V/com.sriram.fileops.MainActivity@44e90428(466): Line read = null
```

Comment: posted. the file hello_files.txt contains only one line: hello world

Comment: @SardorDushamov: Any help is most welcome.. .

Comment: @Sriram - did you ever resolve this problem ?  In any case, just curious, was the device you were using a Samsung ?

Comment: @HowardPautz:Yes. Let me see if I can dig up the code and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from including the permission to access external storage, the following functions for writing to and reading from a file worked.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Write to file:

```
  public void writeToFile() {

        //Step 2. Check if external storage is mounted. 
        boolean mStorageExists;
        boolean mStorageReadWrite;

        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        Log.v(this.toString(), "External media mounted state = " + state);

        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            //media is mounted.
            //Mounted storage is read/write. 
            //Write to the file.

            mStorageExists = true;
            mStorageReadWrite = true;

            Log.v(this.toString(), "Going to write to a file.");

            //get directory.
            File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            Log.v(this.toString(), "Root directory = " + dir.getAbsolutePath());

            String file_to_write = getFileToWrite(dir);  //this returns the exact name of the file.

            String fileName = dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + file_to_write;

            Log.v(this.toString(), "File to write to is present at " + file_to_write);

            File f = new File(dir, file_to_write);
            FileWriter fw = null;
            try {
                fw = new FileWriter(f);
                fw.write(str);
                fw.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.v(this.toString(), "IOException caught in initializing filewriter.");
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            //media is mounted but read only.
            mStorageExists = true;
            mStorageReadWrite = false;
            Log.v(this.toString(), "The media is read-only mounted.");
        } else if( (Environment.MEDIA_NOFS.equals(state)) || (Environment.MEDIA_REMOVED.equals(state)) || (Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED.equals(state))) {
            mStorageExists = false;
            mStorageReadWrite = false;
            Log.v(this.toString(), "There is some problem with the media.");
        }
    }
```

and function to read from file:

```
  public void readFromFile() {

        //Step 1. Check if the storage is available. 
        boolean mStorageAvailable;
        boolean mStorageReadWrite;

        String state = Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED;
        Log.v(this.toString(), "State of media = " + state);

        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            Log.v(this.toString(), "Media is mounted.");
            mStorageAvailable = true;
            mStorageReadWrite = true;

            File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            String file_to_read_from = getFileToRead(dir);
            String fileName = dir + "/" + file_to_read_from;
            Log.v(this.toString(), "Reading from file = " + fileName);

            File f = new File(dir, file_to_read_from);
            //Log.v(this.toString(), "Read from file = " + f.canRead() + " " + f.isFile() + " " + f.exists() + " " + f.length() + " " + f.lastModified());

            try {
                FileReader fis = new FileReader(f);
                Log.v(this.toString(), "Wrapping a buffered reader around file reader.");
                BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(fis, 100);
                String line;
                try {
                    line = bufRead.readLine();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), line, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "Line read = " + line);
                    while(line != null) {
                        Log.v(this.toString(), "Line read = " + line);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), line, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        line = bufRead.readLine();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.v(this.toString(), "IOException found in reading line from file.");
                }   
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                Log.v(this.toString(), "File not found for reading.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, Sriram. I appreciate the follow up. I'll try out the code you posted and let you know.